# Calculating integral image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to calculate the integral image but I am not sure how to achieve doing this by vectorization and by calculating a summed table.  How is this possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use two calls to `cumsum` and transposing the original image:

```
integral_image = cumsum(cumsum(image')');
```

Comment: thanks for your help.Do you know how to show it? 'mat2gray' function does not work for complex number.

Comment: Either plot real and imaginary information separately using `real(integral_image)` and `imag(integral_image)` or plot its absolute value i.e. ´abs(integral_image)`

Comment: Great! But duo to matrix values i was expecting an image that gradually is being changed. What i am getting is a mixed image result.

Comment: Are all values in your image positive? If that is not the case the ii will look a bit strange.

Comment: My image values contains negative amounts.Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: You can avoid doing the transpose twice by specifying the dimension to apply the `cumsum`.  The first call to `cumsum` you can operate along the columns, and the second `cumsum` you can operate along the rows.  Specifically, you can just do this: `integral_image = cumsum(cumsum(image, 2), 1);`  It doesn't matter which direction you process first.

Answer (score 3):

the matlab version is padded with zeros (first row and column)

```
integralImage = cumsum(cumsum(im, 2), 1);
integralImage = padarray(integralImage,[1 1],'pre');
```